# Strncmp issue in a C program

Tags: c, string, strncmp

With the help of this community I have manage to write a code for taking a snippet out from an input xvg file that I need. It's almost working for me but it has a slight issue with strncmp.I want to get a part of this input file file say 1000 to 2000 with lines starting @ and # , so I store those values into the strings called starting_point and stopping_point.Problem is that it doesn't recognize the starting_point and stopping_point. some random output gets stored into the output file.

It works fine small input files.

But doesn't work with input files shown.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <ctype.h>
  #define MAXS 256
  int main (void)
   {
    char line[MAXS] = {0};
    char s1[MAXS];
    int length1,length2;
    char starting_point[MAXS]="1000";
    char stopping_point[MAXS]="2000";
    FILE *fs;

       fs=fopen("md_new.xvg","w");

       while (fgets (line, MAXS, stdin) != NULL) {
          char *p = line;
          size_t len = strlen (line);
        while (len > 0 && (line[len-1] == '\n' || line[len-1] == '\r'))

          line[--len] = 0;    /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */
          length1 = strlen(starting_point);
          length2 = strlen(stopping_point);


          /* storing lines beginning with '#' or '@' or blank lines  */

          **if (*p == '#' || *p == '@' || !*p) 
          {
          fprintf (fs,"%s\n", line);
          printf("%s\n",line);
          }
          if (strncmp (p,starting_point, length1) == 0)
          { 
          fprintf (fs,"%s\n", line);
          printf("%s\n",line);  
          if (strncmp (p,stopping_point, length2) == 0)
          break;                
            }
       }**   

    return 0;
  }
```

---

input file looks something this

```
   #
   #mdrun is part of G R O M A C S:
   #
   #Go Rough, Oppose Many Angry Chinese Serial killers
   #
   @    title "dH/d\xl\f{}, \xD\f{}H"
   @    xaxis  label "Time (ps)"
   @ s0 legend "dH/d\xl\f{} \xl\f{} 0.1"
   @ s1 legend "\xD\f{}H \xl\f{} 0.05"
   @ s2 legend "\xD\f{}H \xl\f{} 0.15"
   0.0000 -33.8598 1.71168 -1.66746
   0.2000 -34.3949 1.73192 -1.702
   0.4000 -31.8213 1.61262 -1.56193
   0.6000 -32.3563 1.63639 -1.59224
   0.8000 -33.6158 1.69898 -1.65539
   1.0000 -32.5242 1.65055 -1.59363
   1.2000 -33.7464 1.70708 -1.6607
   1.4000 -33.0552 1.68563 -1.60985
   1.6000 -32.9946 1.66834 -1.62445
   1.8000 -31.6345 1.60933 -1.54529
   2.0000 -33.1246 1.67736 -1.62769
   2.2000 -33.9822 1.71743 -1.67394
   2.4000 -32.4887 1.64732 -1.59384
   2.6000 -30.0927 1.5349 -1.46508 
   so on till 100000.000
```

Comment: To get help, you'll need to specify exactly what is wrong, what line is failing, what it is doing and what you expected.... And for god sakes please indent correctly

Comment: @mark lakata Dear sir,
I don't understand how indenting works. I am not regular programmer. Wish I could be one. I have corrected my post as much as I can and the problem is with strncmp section.

Comment: The if block to test for stopping point will never get executed because it is inside the if block where starting is tested.

Comment: `while (len > 0 && (line[len-1] == '\n' || line[len-1] == '\r'))` indentation does not correspond to the braces.

Comment: Just a thing please close the file at end .

Answer (score 0):

As you say you are not a programmer, you may consider using something else besides c to do this job.

Consider awk, which can do what you want in one line

```
awk '(/^1000/,/^2000/) || /^[@#]/{print;}' inputfile > outputfile
```